# Vector erase function not working c++

Tags: c++, vector

I'm having strange trouble with the vector erase function. All I want to do is erase the first element of a vector.

So here are the particulars: I have created an object pointer called cv. Within this object pointer's class, there is an integer vector called v. It has a list of numbers.

This object pointer is meant to replicate the affect of a conveyor belt. One of the things I want to do is move the belt forward. This means, in terms of the vector, deleting the number at the top position.

To do this, I wrote `v.erase(v.begin())` in the method responsible for moving the belt forward. But when I ran this, it did not work. I got into an infinite loop where I was constantly looking at the same item.

I then tried `v.erase(0)` but this still did not work. I tried deleting from ranges, but even that wouldn't work. The strange thing is, I'm able to add to the vector without issue, as well as look up items within it. I'm just unable to delete. Any help is appreciated. Please let me know if you need more information from me.

Here is some relevant code:

```
class Belt()
{
vector<int> v;
public:
void MoveBelt();
};

void Belt::MoveBelt()
{
    v.erase(v.begin());
}

int main()
{ 
    char filename[256];
    Belt *cc = new Belt(filename);

    if(condition met)
    {
       cc->MoveBelt();
    }
}
```

For sake of expediency, I've not included the constructor where I read in the data from the file, nor the method where I add the items to the vector. Please take a look and let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: One line of code is worth a hundred words. If you show a tiny self-contained example, someone should be able to spot what's wrong much faster than by reading your description.

Comment: "Did not work" is not very useful. Can you show some code? Also, if you want a conveyor belt have you considered `std::list` instead of a vector?

Comment: Can you show the actual code, stripped down to show the effect you are describing? I would _guess_ that you are `erase()`ing the element in a function which takes `v` as a value parameter, e.g.: `void f(std::vector<int> v) { v.erase(v); }`.

Comment: Use `std::queue` if you want first in first out behavior. It uses `std::deque` underneath by default, which is much better for erasing front elements than `std::vector`.

Comment: @Jon: You need a fairly large amount of `int`s before a `std::list<int>` outperforms a `std::vector<int>` on this operation. If a different data structure should be used it is a `std::deque<int>` although even that is probably slower than using `std::vector<int>` up to a surprisingly high number of elements.

Comment: hi GManNickG, a queue would make most sense. but the problem is, I need to look at the first two elements of the list. With a queue, I can only look at the first and last elements, but nothing in the middle. In that sense, deque would make most sense... But still, this vector operation to remove the front item should work.

Comment: Hey guys, I've edited my question and added code. Please let me know what you think. Thanks.

Comment: The code does not match the description. Please post the real code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a complete example demonstrating that `v.erase(v.begin());` indeed **does** work. Based on that I would guess that you condition is broken. BTW, why exactly are you allocating the object on the heap? The doesn't seem to be any need for doing so.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

class Belt
{
    std::vector<int> v;
 public:
    Belt(std::initializer_list<int> list): v(list.begin(), list.end()) {}
    bool empty() const { return v.empty(); }
    std::vector<int>::const_iterator begin() const { return v.begin(); }
    std::vector<int>::const_iterator end() const { return v.end(); }
    void MoveBelt();
};

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, Belt const& belt)
{
    std::copy(belt.begin(), belt.end(),
              std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout << '[', " "));
    return out << ']';
}

void Belt::MoveBelt()
{
    v.erase(v.begin());
}

int main()
{ 
    Belt cc{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    while (!cc.empty()) {
        std::cout << cc << "\n";
        cc.MoveBelt();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Dietmar, thank you for your response. The skeletal code, including the vector structure, was provided by the instructor. When I tested v.erase(v.begin()) within int main (rather than in a member function of a class) it worked just fine. You could be right - possibly the condition before the call was not triggering. Thank you for your help.